# Using instance property in IIFE

Tags: javascript, undefined, iife

How do I use an instance variable in an IIFE in a method?

I get an error from my start method:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I logged `this.element` in the console and it does come up as undefined, but outside of the IIFE it works fine.

How can I make it work inside the IIFE? I tried passing it in the IIFE as an argument, but that didnt work also.

```
function LiveDateTime(element) {
    'use strict';

    this.element = element;
}

LiveDateTime.prototype = {
    setLocale: function (locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    },

    setOffsetSeconds: function (seconds) {
        this.offsetSeconds = seconds;
    },

    setDaylightSavingTimeSeconds: function (seconds) {
        this.daylightSavingTimeSeconds = seconds;
    },

    start: function () {
        (function update() {
            var now = new Date();
            var now = new Date(
                now.getUTCFullYear(),
                now.getUTCMonth(),
                now.getUTCDate(),
                now.getUTCHours(),
                now.getUTCMinutes(),
                now.getUTCSeconds(),
                now.getUTCMilliseconds()
            );

            this.element.innerHTML = now.toLocalString('fr-FR'); // <--
            this.timeoutId = setTimeout(update, 50); // <--
        })();
    },

    stop: function () {
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);

        this.timeoutId = 0;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store reference to `this` in variable, like this

```
start: function() {
    var self = this;

    (function update() {
        var now = new Date();
        var now = new Date(
            now.getUTCFullYear(),
            now.getUTCMonth(),
            now.getUTCDate(),
            now.getUTCHours(),
            now.getUTCMinutes(),
            now.getUTCSeconds(),
            now.getUTCMilliseconds()
        );

        self.element.innerHTML = now.toLocalString('fr-FR'); // <--
        self.timeoutId = setTimeout(update, 50); // <--
    })();
},
```

Comment: FWIW, I prefer this method over `.bind` - it's a perfect use of JS's ability to close over outer variables, that happens to be used internally by `.bind` but without the overhead of creating a new function object.  I only recommend `.bind` if you have no control over the lexical scope of the function you're calling.